# Trouble starting MySQL

Tags: mysql, xampp, ubuntu-16.04

So, as the title states, I am having trouble starting MySQL through XAMPP.

When I run

```
sudo service mysql status
```

it shows:

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-01-13 09:47:08 CST; 19s ago
Process: 26229 ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post (code=e
Process: 26225 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exi
Main PID: 26228 (mysqld)
CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
       └─26228 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Jan 13 09:46:38 logan-Latitude-E6320 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server
Jan 13 09:47:08 logan-Latitude-E6320 systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
```

However, when I try to run mysql through XAMPP, it will not start. It shows these errors in the log:

```
2017-01-13  9:43:08 140336956557120 [ERROR] InnoDB: /opt/lampp/var/mysql/ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write mode
2017-01-13  9:43:08 140336956557120 [ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!
2017-01-13  9:43:08 140336956557120 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2017-01-13  9:43:08 140336956557120 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2017-01-13  9:43:08 140336956557120 [ERROR] mysqld: File '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/aria_log_control' not found (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
2017-01-13  9:43:08 140336956557120 [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Can't open file' when trying to use aria control file '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/aria_log_control'
2017-01-13  9:43:08 140336956557120 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2017-01-13  9:43:08 140336956557120 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2017-01-13  9:43:08 140336956557120 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2017-01-13  9:43:08 140336956557120 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2017-01-13  9:43:08 140336956557120 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2017-01-13  9:43:08 140336956557120 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I have tried to chmod to adjust privileges with aria_log_control and ibdata1 files to allow read and write access (I tried 755 and 775) but it doesnt seem to be effective.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.